# PostgreSQL user creation with with only few features

Tags: postgresql

Currently I'm working as an PostgreSQL database admin and I'm new to this admin. I need to create an user with only create,insert,update,select,alter table using pg admin 4 for particular database and schema

DB Version 9.6.3

Comment: About the insert failing -- you might need to grant insert privilege on the sequence (as well as the table)... assuming there's a sequence on the table.

Comment: I have done that too but still same issue.

Comment: Oops, I meant 'usage' & 'select' on the sequence.

Comment: Show us the DDL that you ran and the SQL that resulted in the error. **[Edit]** your question. Do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @David-SkyMesh  : I have edited the question